# D3 divgrid.js with json data

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I have a data source that I'm converting to CSV to be able to use it to create a grid.

The data is as follows:

```
{
"Name": "Emily",
"Age": "10"
}
```

When I convert it I can see that the data appears as follows:

```
Name,Age
"Emily","10"
```

But when I run the html I get the output as follows:

```
0
N
a
m
e
,
A
g
e
"
E
m
i
l
y
"
,
"
1
0
"
```

The code I'm using is the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<body>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script src="divgrid.js"></script>
<script>
    var notas = [
    {
    "Name": "Emily",
    "Age": "10"
    }];
    const replacer = (key, value) => value === null ? '' : value 
    const header = Object.keys(notas[0])
    let csv = notas.map(row => header.map(fieldName => JSON.stringify(row[fieldName], replacer)).join(','))
    csv.unshift(header.join(','))
    csv = csv.join('\r\n')
    console.log(csv)
    var grid = d3.divgrid();
    d3.select('body')
        .datum(csv)
        .call(grid);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume "divgrid" is from [here](http://bl.ocks.org/syntagmatic/3687826)?

If so, you **don't need** csv data, you need your data like you already have it.   In the linked example `d3.csv` is converting csv data to the format you already have; an array of objects!

Full example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
  <style>
    <style type="text/css"> html,
    body {
      background: #f7f7f7;
      height: 100%;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      color: #111;
      font-family: Ubuntu, Helvetica, sans-serif;
      font-size: 12px;
      line-height: 1.35em;
    }
    
    a {
      color: #6be;
      text-decoration: none;
    }
    
    .row,
    .header,
    .cell {
      height: 18px;
    }
    
    .row,
    .header {
      clear: left;
    }
    
    .header {
      font-weight: bold;
    }
    
    .cell {
      float: left;
      overflow: hidden;
      white-space: nowrap;
      width: 100px;
    }
    
    .col-0 {
      width: 180px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://bl.ocks.org/syntagmatic/raw/3687826/ccc6c63b6f6df611930c8fd6d3ddf5daebe0ddf2/divgrid.js"></script>
  <script>
    var notas = [{
      "Name": "Emily",
      "Age": "10"
    }];
    var grid = d3.divgrid();
    d3.select('body')
      .datum(notas)
      .call(grid);
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks Mark. Wow, I was not expecting the css code to be formatting the table.